Is there a simple way to merge one branch to another with a workflow?
We a two branches: main and prod. Both branches are used as refrence to build a website. Now I wanted a workflow that reacts to a certain commit message to be triggered. It should then auto merge main into prod.
I tried a lot. I dont even know if thats the right approach. I get Errors for merge conflicts but if I run the command locally with the same settings it won't work.
name: Merge main into prod

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  merge-main-into-prod:
    name: Merge main into prod 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout main branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: main
      
      - name: Set up Git user
        run: |
          git config user.name "GitHub Action"
          git config user.email "action@github.com"
    
      - name: Get last commit message
        id: get_message
        run: |
          last_commit_message=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%s)
          echo "Last commit message: $last_commit_message"
          echo "message=$last_commit_message" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Check commit message pattern
        id: check_pattern
        run: |
          if echo "${{ env.message }}" | grep -qE '^Merge pull request #[0-9]+ from *****/cms/Changelog/index$'; then
            echo "Pattern matched"
            echo "match=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          else
            echo "Pattern did not match"
            echo "match=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          fi

      - name: Checkout prod branch
        if: env.match == 'true'
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: prod
      
      - name: Fetch main branch
        if: env.match == 'true'
        run: |
          git fetch origin main:main
    
      - name: Merge main into prod
        if: env.match == 'true'
        run: |
          git merge main --no-ff --allow-unrelated-histories -m "Merging changes from main to prod"
          git push origin prod


Are you committing to main? If not, you should never have conflicts

Well, yes through Decap CMS and when I need to adjust configs for example. I tested it locally to merge main onto prod -> no conflicts there so I dont get it
